# Click event only works on first click after pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

I use this popup plugin for jquery and get some strange behaviour. I have contacted the creator but got no answer and would like to ask here if there is any general problem with my code.

The setup:
Regular html links that open a page in a new tab (for JS disabled users).

The js below to catch the link click and animate a popup instead of following the link.

The problem:
It works the first click on every page load but therafter a click follows the href instead.

js

```
 $("a[class*='popupbox-link']").live("click",function (e) {
        if($("#popupbox").length == 0){
            $('body').append('<div id="popupbox"><a class="bClose">Stäng</a><div id="pContent"></div></div>');
        }
        var url = this.href;
        $("#popupbox").bPopup({contentContainer:'#pContent', loadUrl: url });
        e.stopPropagation();

        return false
    });
```

Comment: sounds like there is an javascript error. Do you have firebug open and if so do you get any errors

Comment: you are right I get errors on on the 2nd-n clicks: error 1 `$("#popupbox").bPopup is not a function
[Stanna vid fel] $("#popupbox").bPopup({contentContainer:'#pContent', loadUrl: url });` how come? since it works the first time. error 2: `$("#popupbox").bPopup is not a function
[Stanna vid fel] (158 out of range 3)`

Comment: My guess is because you are adding the `$('#popupbox').bPopup` everytime they click something. You should just add it once

Comment: But the url is decided of which link is clicked so it need to be added. Or how do you mean?

Comment: here is the plugin address if it clears anything http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the event propagation

```
$("a[class*='popupbox-link']").live("click",function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   if($("#popupbox").length == 0){
      $(‘body’).append(‘Stäng‘);
   }
   var url = this.href;
   $("#popupbox").bPopup({contentContainer:'#pContent', loadUrl: url });


   return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didnt solve it, the change resulted in: click 1 the browser followed the link and opened the popup. following clicks browser just followed the link.

Comment: It should work fine with stopPropagation. In the second click are you getting any js error?

Comment: I think the popupbox is getting removed from the dom tree when you close the popup. But you call still stop the event propagation. I have edited my answer please try it.

Comment: Some problem with bPopup plugin. Take a look at it.

Comment: put $(“#popupbox”).bPopup({contentContainer:’#pContent’, loadUrl: url }); in try catch block it should work fine but the popup will not work from second click onwards.

Comment: ok but it works on the demo page. Also what did you mean was the try catch a solution or to show it didnt work either. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using delegate instead of live